# Find Count in repeated string

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a string which I need to repeat at least 'n' number of times. Then for given number of 'n' i need to count the occurrence of letter 'a'
For example 
String - 'aab'
n - 10
I need to iterate string 'aab' so that total count should be at least equals to 'n' and then  I need to find count of 'a'
Please see the question here https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.next();
    long n = in.nextLong();
    long count = 0;
    String test = "";
    for(long i =0;i <= n; i++)
    {
      test = test.concat(s);  
    }

     long len = test.length();   
    for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(i < n )
            {
                if((int)test.charAt(i) == 97 )
                 {
                     count ++;
                 }

            }
        else
            {
                break;
            }
     }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

This works when the input is small. For the following case it gives out error saying Terminated due to timeout.
String - 'a'
n - 10000000000000

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think `test` is necessary for getting the answer, but just so you know, you should never use concatenation in a loop. It's incredibly costly and slow. Instead, use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: ok. but it fails for the second test case where string is 'a' and n is 100000000000

Comment: The timeout was probably because of how slow concatenation is in a loop.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. This is the error when I use StringBuilder

Comment: I'll give you a hint: use `n / s.length` and `n % s.length` to determine how many times the string occurs in `n` characters. Don't use `test`.

Comment: Hint: you want us to spent our time to help you. So you please spend the 1 minute it takes to properly format/indent your question, esp. the code parts in there. The "preview" function exists for a reason!

Answer (score 1):

Just count using the initial String and multiply by n.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string  Please see the problem here

Comment: I don't think the point of hackerrank is for you to pawn off your questions on others.  You should consider figuring this out yourself.

Comment: @chan You should include that in the question, and clarify that `n` represents the number of characters, and not the number of repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Find the length(`len`) of the string. [Eg: "aba" has length 3]
2. Find the value of `s`=(int)(n/len) and `rem`=n%len
3. Find the number of times `a` occurs in the original string, say `k`.According to the example, it is 2. [2 times in "aba"]
4. Iterate over the string from `i=0` to `i<rem`, and find out the number of times `a` occurs, say `p`.
5. Your answer is `k*s + p`